# How to dynamically determine the upstream task from the current task

Tags: airflow, jinja2

In one of my operators, I am trying to get data from an upstream task. The operator is not a PythonOperator, so I don't have explicit access to the context. Unfortunately, to get access without the context, AirFlow requires you to use Jinja Templates (Note for any airflow dev - please allow call back functions instead!).

In order for me to dynamically determine the upstream job's `task_id` and then use *xcom* to obtain its data, I use this template string:

```
'{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=ti.task.get_direct_relatives(upstream=True)[0].task_id) }}'
```

And while the above works, I can't help think that there must be a better way to get hold of the direct parent task (as opposed to cycling through all the direct upstream tasks). For one thing, if a task has two parents, then the above could fail.

Is there a way to do this?